# Is it possible to reuse the same sumif range?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, google-spreadsheets

In the following table, I constantly reevaluate a2:a4 to run different calculations against it. In a real table it would have been thousands of rows like it.

Is there a way to somehow store a2:a4 in a single cell and thus run sumif against it?

| Num1 | Num2 | Sumif1 | SumIf2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 3 | =sumif(a2:a6, a2) | =sumif(a2:a6, b2) |
| 4 | 5 | =sumif(a2:a6, a3) | =sumif(a2:a6, b3) |
| 6 | 7 | =sumif(a2:a6, a4) | =sumif(a2:a6, b4) |
| 2 | 4 | =sumif(a2:a6, a5) | =sumif(a2:a6, b5) |
| 4 | 2 | =sumif(a2:a6, a6) | =sumif(a2:a6, b6) |

If this was index/match, I would have stored match only once for each row and then run multiple indexes against it, thus greatly speed up the process when much data is involved:

| Num1 | Num2 | Match | Index1 | Index2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 3 | =match(a2, a2:a6) | =index(b2:b6, c2) | =index(a2:a6, c2) |
| 4 | 5 | =match(a3, a2:a6) | =index(b2:b6, c3) | =index(a2:a6, c3) |
| 6 | 7 | =match(a4, a2:a6) | =index(b2:b6, c4) | =index(a2:a6, c4) |
| 2 | 4 | =match(a5, a2:a6) | =index(b2:b6, c5) | =index(a2:a6, c5) |
| 4 | 2 | =match(a6, a2:a6) | =index(b2:b6, c6) | =index(a2:a6, c6) |

Comment: a cell cannot contain an array.

Comment: And even if it could, SUMIF does not accept arrays and only accepts ranges.

Comment: Did you test with SUMIFS function? https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/sumifs-function-c9e748f5-7ea7-455d-9406-611cebce642b?ui=en-us&rs=en-gb&ad=gb

Comment: Not sure how it's relevant. SUNIFS is for AND statements while I'm talking about two independent check ups.

Comment: @LWC ,, honestly I'm unable to understand that what you are trying to achieve,,, considering formula `=sumif(a2:a6, a2)` &  which is unusual & looks like unproductive formula,,, coz SUMIF has `(Criteria Range, Criteria, SUM Range)`, and this will return the A2 value only,,, possibly you are trying get SUM from Column matching Range of values  like ,,, `=SUM(SUMIF(A2:A20, {"A","B"}, B2:B20))` !!

Comment: In the real context I do use SUM range. For easier syntax table I skipped it. I just want to know if I can avoid running different unrelated criterias over the same range.

Answer (score 0):

There are at least three easy ways to achieve what you wish to do.

The simplest is a single step changing the range reference from relative referencing to absolute referencing:

$a2:$a6

You would do that in the first cell of any column, then copy the formula down as needed. These could be existing columns as shown in your examples, and in any new uses you have.

The next easiest, and my preference for anything I wish to use as extensively as you seem to want to use this, is to create a Named Range. In its `Refers to:` field, you would enter:

```
=$A$2:$A$6
```

Given the upcoming `LAMBDA()` function and its increased value in combination with Named Ranges (and not necessarily just ONE Named Range either), using Named Ranges should soon lose the disdain of so many. Good time to start getting used to them, I say!

A third pretty easy method, though not necessarily as simple as the preceding two as it comes with effort, small, and baggage, potentially noticeable. That is to use the `INDIRECT()` function to enclose a string, `a2:a6`, and so return the contents of the range to the formula. However, since the address is in a string, it will not be changed by the Excel engine when copied to other cells. I say "effort" because it being changed in the future could be problematic in some cases, and it is usually harder for the less experienced users to understand and therefore for them to take over stewardship for a spreadsheet. One doesn't get promoted if one cannot pass on one's duties to assume new ones, so... that's some amount of "problematic." I say "baggage" because of the volatility issue with `INDIRECT()` which can matter if you have a very large-to-huge spreadsheet, especially a complex one, an older copy of Excel, AND a fairly old computer. It doesn't matter in any way, shape, or form if you have a <3-5 year old computer unless it is very complex, and perhaps not even then. Not. At. All. Contrary to what you read endlessly.

If your actual use really uses that four cell range, you have no concerns with `INDIRECT()` whatsoever.

In place of a Named Range, you can enter a string for the range in a cell, then reference that cell using `INDIRECT()`.

Comment: The question asks about refusing number of calculations ACROSS cells, what you explain is reducing it WITHIN cell.

Answer (score 0):

> I constantly reevaluate a2:a4

Actually Excel is not doing any calculations for that evaluation, so there is not really opportunity here to improve performance.

If you want to improve readability, you can use [named range](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/define-and-use-names-in-formulas-4d0f13ac-53b7-422e-afd2-abd7ff379c64), or convert your data to a table and use [structured reference](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/using-structured-references-with-excel-tables-f5ed2452-2337-4f71-bed3-c8ae6d2b276e#:%7E:text=That%20combination%20of%20table%20and,table%20that%20references%20table%20data.)